# Multithreaded TCP client using QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, tcp

I am writing a TCP client application in Qt, it has many independent threads each of them communicates to server.

I have a simple architectural question: should I create new QTcpSocket for each request and connect each time or rather use single QTcpSocket for all requests? Which approach is recommended?

Personally, I prefer creating new sockets, this makes the code much simpler. But for some reason the tcp connection (`waitForConnected` or `connected` signal) takes quite a long time which slows down the whole application.

Comment: A clear case of: It depends.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. In a server program I used `tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Localhost, port)` to start TCP server. It turns out there's something wrong with this call: when I use it like this every client connection takes 1-1.5 seconds! But when I change it to `tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port)` everything works fine, delays are just 2-3 milliseconds. Very strange, is it a bug in Qt?

Comment: More a case of strange code and strange configuration.Where are your clients running? How do they connect at all when your server is only listening to localhost? You need some sophisticated network configuration to achieve this. Good chance there lies the cause for your delay.

Comment: This was a test configuration obviously. Both programs were running on my dev. machine so I used localhost.